# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lrx/subjects/ReplaySubject; on 22 API

Tags: android, gradle, rx-java, noclassdeffounderror, rx-java2

I'm using chat-sdk from https://github.com/chat-sdk/chat-sdk-android in my Android project.  I added four of it's modules to my application: chat-sdk-core, chat-sdk-firebase-adapter, chat-sdk-firebase-file-storage, chat-sdk-firebase-push, chat-sdk-ui. I set `multiDexEnabled` to `true`. I added multidex library to app gradle file. My `RxApp` class extends `MultiDexApplication` instead of `Application`. I even add `MultiDex.install(this)` in attachBaseContext method of `RxApp` class. But still when I run my app on Android Lollipop the app crashes on start throwing `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lrx/subjects/ReplaySubject;`. When I run the project on Android Nougat everything works fine. Any ideas?

This is my gradle build file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
apply plugin: 'org.greenrobot.greendao'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "kktest.gandi.com.kktest"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 17
        versionName "0.3.6.3"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file(RELEASE_STORE_FILE_RELATIVE)
            storePassword RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
            keyAlias RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
            keyPassword RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
        }
        debug {
            storeFile file(DEBUG_STORE_FILE_RELATIVE)
            storePassword DEBUG_STORE_PASSWORD
            keyAlias DEBUG_KEY_ALIAS
            keyPassword DEBUG_KEY_PASSWORD
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release

            //minifyEnabled false
            //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug

            //minifyEnabled false
            //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}


greendao {
    schemaVersion 18
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    // Retrofit
    // Type-safe HTTP client for Android and Java by Square, Inc.
    // http://square.github.io/retrofit/
    // https://github.com/square/retrofit

    // GreenDAO
    // https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO
    compile 'org.greenrobot:greendao:3.2.2'
    // if you want to use encrypted databases
    //compile 'net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:3.5.4'

    // EasyImage
    // EasyImage allows you to easily capture images from the gallery, camera or documents without creating lots of boilerplate.
    // https://github.com/jkwiecien/EasyImage

    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.5.0'
    compile 'com.github.jkwiecien:EasyImage:2.0.3'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:1.4.3'
    compile 'com.github.gcacace:signature-pad:1.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'

    // RxTuples is a library to smooth RxJava usage by adding simple Tuple creation functions.
    // https://github.com/pakoito/RxTuples
    compile 'com.github.pakoito:RxTuples:1.0.+'

    // Material Dialogs
    // https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs
    compile('com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.4.2') {
        transitive = true
    }

    // DataPickerDialog for gallery
    compile('com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.5.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.tajchert:nammu:1.1.3'
    compile project(path: ':chat-sdk-ui')
    compile project(path: ':chat-sdk-firebase-adapter')
    compile project(path: ':chat-sdk-firebase-push')
    compile project(path: ':chat-sdk-firebase-file-storage')

}
task copyDependencies(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'dependencies'
}
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '25.3.1'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This below is my Logcat

```
02-15 16:58:28.532 12088-12088/kktest.gandi.com.kktest E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: kktest.gandi.com.kktest, PID: 12088
                                                                         java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lrx/subjects/ReplaySubject;
                                                                             at com.kube.kubenz.dev.core.RxApp.<clinit>(RxApp.java:50)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                             at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1606)
                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:995)
                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:980)
                                                                             at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:558)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4526)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "rx.subjects.ReplaySubject" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/kktest.gandi.com.kktest-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/kktest.gandi.com.kktest-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/kktest.gandi.com.kktest-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/kktest.gandi.com.kktest-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/kktest.gandi.com.kktest-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/kktest.gandi.com.kktest-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/kktest.gandi.com.kktest-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/kktest.gandi.com.kktest-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/kktest.gandi.com.kktest-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/kktest.gandi.com.kktest-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/kktest.gandi.com.kktest-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/kktest.gandi.com.kktest-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/kktest.gandi.com.kktest-2/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                                             at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                             at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                                                                             at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                                                             at com.kube.kubenz.dev.core.RxApp.<clinit>(RxApp.java:50) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                                                                             at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1606) 
                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:995) 
                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:980) 
                                                                             at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:558) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4526) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
                                                                            Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: rx.subjects.ReplaySubject
                                                                             at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                                                             at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
                                                                             at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
                                                                             at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                                                                                    ... 17 more
                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```